# Cassandra Rolling Tombstones

Tags: cassandra

I am doing some simple operations in Cassandra, to keep things simple I am using a **single node** . I have one single row and I add 10,000 columns to it, next I go and delete these 10,000 columns, after a while I add 10,000 more columns to it and then delete them after some time and so on ... The deletes will delete all the columns in that one row.

Here's the thing which I don't understand, even though I delete them I see the size of the database increase, my **GCGracePeriod** is set to 0 and I am using **Leveled Compaction Strategy**.

If I understand the tombstones correctly, they should be deleted after the first major compaction, it appears that they are not deleted, even after running nodetool compact command.

I read on some mailing list that these are rolling tombstones (if you frequently update and delete the same row) and are not handled by major compaction. So my question is when are they deleted ? if not then the data would just grow, which i personally think is bad. To make matters worst I could not find any documentation about this particular effect.

Answer (score 3):

First, as you're discovering, this isn't a really good idea.  At the very least you should use row-level deletes, not individual column deletes.

Second, There is no such thing as a major compaction with LCS; `nodetool compact` is a no-op.

Finally, Cassandra 1.2 improves compaction a lot for workloads that generate a lot of tombstones: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3442

Comment: That's what I am resorting to now, row level deletes. But, since Cassandra is so column oriented it felt a bit odd to use rows. 'nodetool compact' is a no-op for LCS, that's a news to me thanks !. Unfortunately, we are using 1.0.12 and don't see moving to 1.2 at-least for some time.

Comment: Cassandra is row oriented actually and it's most efficient to use it at row-level.